# I have installed Gazebo 1-9 and there is some errors when it starts in Ubuntu 13.04 (raring)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, i have Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) and i have installed Gazebo 1-9 following the Gazebo's tutorials.
After that  i type on the terminal "gazebo" and the gui starts but have two errors and one Warning:

Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:206] Unable to connect to model database using [http://gazebosim.org/models//database.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.

Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [1,0471975511965976] for key[horizontal_fov]

Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [0,100000001] for key[near]

What have i to do?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5518/i-have-installed-gazebo-1-9-and-there-is-some-errors-when-it-starts-in-ubuntu-13.04-(raring)/) by [Stefano Aringhieri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/643/stefano-aringhieri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like a locale issue (error interpreting commas as decimal separators). Try setting LANG="C" or LANG="en_US"

The warning message about the model database has been fixed in gazebo 2.2. It could also indicate that you don't have an internet connection.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefano Aringhieri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/643/stefano-aringhieri/) on 2014-02-21**:
Try setting LANG="C" or LANG="en_US" ---> The error remains

"The warning message about the model database has been fixed in gazebo 2.2. It could also indicate that you don't have an internet connection." --->and now how can i install the model database with an internet connection? Thanks!

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-04-15**:
I still get this error in gazebo 3.0

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-04-15**:
Stefano, models will automatically download when you use them (either by loading an SDF file, or dragging them into a scene via the GUI). I'll setup a VM with a different language to debug this problem further.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-02**:
I was unable to reproduce it using spanish (es_ES) locales for LC_ALL and LANG. Andrei, could please the output of printenv command and the error message you see in gazebo 3.0? Thanks.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-05-05**:
I copied printenv here `http://pastebin.com/7aEGm8dQ` and the gazebo error is `Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [1,0471975511965976] for key[horizontal_fov] Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [0,100000001] for key[near]`

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-05**:
Is it a fedora system? I'm suspecting from LC_NUMERIC. Could you please test: LC_NUMERIC=C LC_COLLATE=C gazebo?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-05-05**:
it's ubuntu 13.04, LC_NUMERIC=C did the job, does this actually influence gazebo during runtime?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-05**:
Indeed. It does affect (not only) all kind of input/output operations that uses . Reference could be found: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/. Could you please submit an issue in sdformat about this? We can patch it to overwrite user locales.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/847/peci1/) on 2014-06-17**:
There doesn't seem to be a maintainer for libsdformat1, so reporting a bug is not allowed...

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-07-22**:
Ummm, we are maintaining and support sdformat 1.4 branch and 2.0 branch. Where did you read that there is no maintainer for libsdformat1?

**Comment by [Hugo Costelha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/360/hugo-costelha/) on 2014-10-10**:
Just to let others now that the issue is reported here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issue/60/error-when-starting-gazebo-if-lc_numeric

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The environment variable that could affect directly the representation of floating point numbers is **LC_NUMERIC**. Setting it to C should fix the problem. A quick fix would be:

> LC_NUMERIC=C gazebo

Any other mechanism to make this change permanent (bashrc, bash_profile, ...) is recommended.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1